# Is this a legit macOS modal, or a malware attempt?

Tags: security, software-update, malware

The following modal dialog prompting for a software update password has been popping up a few times and I really do not know what to make of it:

1. it seems to be controlled by the Finder (not a browser or any particular app)
2. it does not seem to be part of the standard macOS update workflow, but coincidentally, there *is* an update available (as seen in my System Preferences)
3. I cannot find a single hit on Google for the exact wording in that modal
4. It seems plausible that it could come from one of the (very few) system extensions I have installed, but no indication of which.

Any idea how I could confirm whether this is legit (although horrible UX) or Malware. And if the latter: how could I go about finding the source (the fact that this pops-up would indicate that the system is already partly compromised).

[image]

Comment: Download the free version of [Malwarebytes](https://support.malwarebytes.com/hc/en-us/articles/360038479294-Install-Malwarebytes-for-Mac) and give your Mac a scan. It is usually pretty good at finding nasty and/or sketchy stuff. I run it weekly. In fact, since it is early morning on Monday where I am on the planet, I'm going to run it now!

Comment: I did run Malwarebyte, and it did not find anything. But the above modal is so mindbogglingly stupid UX if it is a legit Apple modal, that I am forced to consider a worst case scenario.

Comment: Cancel that dialog and see whether you genuinely have an update waiting. 'Apple' | System Settings | General | Software Update. If there is, update it from there (a trusted interaction) and then see if that popup stops appearing after. If not, then it's from another source.

Comment: I've never seen that _particular_ modal, but there similar low-fi modals that pop up from time to time.

Comment: I did cancel and go through an active process to check for, and run, the OS update. That being said, the fact that it popped up roughly around the time of a MacOS update does not particularly reassure me (it's a 50% chance at any given time)…

Comment: FWIW, the modal that pops up when going through Settings has the exact same wording, and very similar (but not identical) UI. So I guess the above modal is legit.
But I still cannot believe what possessed Apple to foster such horrid infosec practices.

Comment: Sorry I missed that you'd seen a pending update in your OP. Great minds think alike ;-)

Comment: @Dave You are correct in your assessment of this being an absolutely horrible UX from several points of view, including the infosec failings.  But this type of unverifiable prompt (whether from cmdline or GUI) has been around forever and in multiple contexts.  Another related example: "legitimate" company-sent emails directing us to follow a link to log into an external site and enter all sorts of personal data up to and including login credentials, but without any way of verifying the authenticity of the original email.

Comment: @jrw32982 indeed, bad UX and poor infosec abound. But one might hold the Apple to a much higher standard than random companies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears the same as when you run an update. However, to confirm I would recommend doing the following:

Cancel out of the alert and go to System Settings. Press to install the update. You will receive an alert shortly after that looks like this and can enter your password to install the update.

You can also download & run Malwarebytes to be safe - it doesn't hurt.

Comment: More or less came to the conclusion (noticed that the modal popping up when manually triggering the update from System Settings was near-identical).
Would have loved to hear the rationale for such a stupid UX, but in any case, I am at least reassured that I am not infected somehow.